# Criar OU Atualizar -> MySQL

Tags: mysql

Existe algo 'nativo' do MYSQL que faça um Update OR Create?

Algo que seja mais performático do que o SELECT, validação e o INSERT/UPDATE como normalmente é feito.

Não me refiro a métodos que simplifiquem isso via aplicação, minha duvida é sobre essa ação sob a responsabilidade do próprio banco de dados.

Exemplo de como uso no Laravel:

```
App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99]
);
```

Porém, isso não deixa de ser apenas uma abstração do SELECT e a condição.

No MongoDB, temos isso:

```
Person.update(
  { name : 'TED' },
  { name : 'TED', age : 50 },
  { upsert : true }
,callback );
```

O parametro `upsert` faz com que o update or create funcione.

Comment: Acredito que todos esses metódos internamente verifiquem se já 
 existe algo no `DB` através de algum tipo de consulta e validação, então creio que não há mudança em performance ao encapsular em um método, a vantagem seria só em simplificar e evitar repetições.

Comment: Caique, o problema é que essa verificação ja é de fato uma consulta, entao significa que para atualizar algo eu tenha que dar dois comandos no banco de dados, entendeu? Logo, dobra o tempo do processo. Para poucos itens é imperceptível  mas estou trabalhando com muitos itens e isso esta fazendo bastante diferença.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você tiver uma chave primária ou um índice único, você consegue usar o evento `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
INSERT INTO `sua_tabela` (`campo1`, `campo2`)
VALUES ('informação1', 'informação2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `campo1` = 'informação1', `campo2` = 'informação2';
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 1):

Boa Tarde, existe sim, o `REPLACE` nativo do `MySQL.`

Você pode usar dessa maneira: `REPALCE INTO table...`

Caso exista um registro ele atualiza os campos, caso não exista ele insere em sua tabela.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html